# My mac is not surfing the net properly!

Tags: mac, internet, connection

To start with i am writing this from windows on my mac. I have a problem with the internet on my mac. i it not surfing the internet properly, for example, I can't access any of google's websites (gmail, google voice, google.com, any other google sites) i can't access some other sites as well for some reason (on all three browsers: chrome, safari, and firefox). On the other hand, I can access other sites like random different sites so I believe the problem might be with the cache however i flushed DNS caches on mac. All the sites work perfectly on my window on mac.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `ping google.com` and `dig google.com` via the Terminal application in `/Applications/Utilities`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen strange problems where ISP-provided DNS servers stop working properly/quickly, or home routers stop functioning as DNS servers.  Try running these commands in the Terminal (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app):

```
ping -c 4 google.com
ping -c 4 yahoo.com
ping -c 4 microsoft.com
ping -c 4 apple.com

ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
ping -c 4 208.67.222.222.
ping -c 4 4.2.2.2
```

If the first set of addresses come back "Request timeout..." but the last three come back "64 bytes...", then it sounds like your DNS servers are not set up properly or are not working.  Try going to System Preferences → Network → (Your Interface) → Advanced → DNS.  On the left side, delete any DNS servers that are currently listed (grey addresses come from DHCP and cannot be deleted), then add these two addresses:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

These are Google's Public DNS servers, and can probably be trusted to be reliable.

Comment: this did not work, same problem... i tried open dns and i still have the same problem. I can access everything on windows but not on my mac.

Comment: Were you able to ping every one of the addresses?

Comment: yeah i pinged the addresses google.com gives time out and the others (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) give 64 bytes. However, google.com gives timeout then starts giving 64 bytes.